# Stop Parent .htaccess file from Propagating to Child Directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, propagation

I've got a .htaccess file in the web root directory of the server that has a line like:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php http://my-new-site.com
```

I've discovered that all index.php files in sub-directories respect that redirect too. Okay... I didn't know that .htaccess files in parent directories propagated though to their children. Good to know. But is there any way to stop that behavior? Can I restrict the .htaccess file to only affect files in the same directory?

Basically, how do I stop .htaccess rules from propagating to child directories?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it, and it doesn't work this way for me. Are you sure you're not using `RedirectMatch` which (with those values) would just match /index.php anywhere in the request string. What does the rest of the .htaccess look like? Are there .htaccesses in any of the affected directories? What do they look like?

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Thanks for checking. No, I'm using Redirect 301 and the only content in the rest of the .htaccess file is some error handling stuff. There are no other .htaccess files in any of the subdirectories either. 

I'm inheriting this project and server... so there might be some other Apache magic happening somewhere. I'll continue to dig...

Comment: Try changing the rule to say `/blub.php` and see if `/subdir/blub.php` also redirects. Also check the httpd.conf file and related files for anything interesting. Lastly check if there's an index.php in the subdir that might be doing a redirect in PHP code.