# RewriteEngine conditional directories

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have the following site structure

```
index.php   
services.php   
contact.php   
/admin
```

and the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.php [L]  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+\.)+php\ HTTP  
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This successfully tidies up my URLs and directs to the correct pages.

However it prevents any functions being carried out in admin where $_POST and $_GET is being used a lot.

So is there a way to prevent the rule being carried out in /admin or restrict it to only being carried out in top level pages?

Comment: I think overriding the .htaccess file with a blank in the admin folder cleans out anything from the root.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop Parent .htaccess file from Propagating to Child Directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382631/stop-parent-htaccess-file-from-propagating-to-child-directories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this rule right after `RewriteEngine on` line (before both of your rules):

```
RewriteRule ^admin(/.*|)$ - [L]
```

Comment: I seem to have to include this AFTER my rules otherwise it ended up with a bunch of different errors. Everything seems fine though thanks.